LigPlot (LigPlus) Giving Different Interactions on Command Line and GUI
I am trying to determine the interaction of the targeted amino acid with other amino acids, but I am having trouble. When I pass a PDB file of a protein that has ligands, I can see the interactions. However, when I pass a PDB file of a protein without ligands, I don't see any interactions. Interestingly, when I run this ligand-free PDB file through LigPlot GUI, it shows the interactions.
PDB ID example: 1BBT
Here is the code I wrote:
filename = "1BBT.pdb"
ligPlotLoc = "LigPlus"
programLoc = f"{ligPlotLoc}/lib/exe_linux64/"
ligplot_prm = f"{ligPlotLoc}/lib/params/ligplot.prm"
atom_number = 82
chain_ID = 1

os.system(f"{programLoc}hbadd {filename} {ligPlotLoc}/components.cif -wkdir ./")
os.system(f"{programLoc}hbplus -L -f hbplus.rc -h 2.90 -d 3.90 -N {filename} -wkdir ./")
os.system(f"{programLoc}hbplus -L -f hbplus.rc -h 2.70 -d 3.35 {filename} -wkdir ./")
os.system(f"{programLoc}ligplot {filename} {atom_number} {atom_number} {chain_ID} -wkdir ./ -prm {ligplot_prm} -ctype 1")

Below is the image of the interaction I obtained from running the LigPlot command line.

Below is the interaction that I am trying to get using the LigPlot command line but haven't been able to. However, I successfully obtained it using the LigPlot GUI. But wanted to get it done through ligplot command


its not free, so you better ask to the user community or here https://www.ebi.ac.uk/thornton-srv/software/LigPlus/contactus.html In case of any problems or questions relating to LigPlot+, please contact (preferably by e-mail):
Roman Laskowski
European Bioinformatics Institute,
Wellcome Trust Genome Campus,
Hinxton,
Cambridge, CB10 1SD,
United Kingdom
Phone Number: +44 (0)1223 492 542
Fax Number: +44 (0)1223 494 468
Email: roman@ebi.ac.uk
Personal Page: http://www.ebi.ac.uk/~roman/

Thank you @pippo1980
